# C#: Replace random letters with letters from another keyboard layout

Tags: c#, replace, letters

Sorry for my bad english. So, i have a code.

```
    public Random rnd = new Random();

    public string RandomizeLetters(string text)
    {
        string variations = "";

        foreach (var letter in text)
        {
            var а = new List<string> { "а", "аa" };
            var е = new List<string> { "е", "еe" };
            var о = new List<string> { "о", "оo" };
            var р = new List<string> { "р", "рp" };
            var с = new List<string> { "с", "сc" };
            var у = new List<string> { "у", "уy" };
            var х = new List<string> { "х", "хx" };

            var alphavite = new List<List<string>> { а, е, о, р, с, у, х };

            var res = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var x in alphavite)
            {
                if (x.Exists(e => e.EndsWith(letter.ToString())))
                {
                    res.Append(x[1][rnd.Next(0, x[1].Length)]);
                }
            }

            res.Append(letter.ToString());

            variations += res;
        }

        return variations.ToString();
    }
```

This code replaces random letters with letters that are visually similar to letters from a different keyboard layout, in my case, from Russian keyboard layout to the English keyboard layout.
But instead of the desired result, I get text with duplicate characters.

Here is the text I want to process:

> Для проверки наличия в вашем тексте символов из другого языка - скопируйте исходный текст, вставьте его в поле ниже, и выберите нужный чекбокс языка

But the text that I get at the output:

> Для пpроовeеpрки нaаличия в ваашeем теекcстeе cсимвоолоов из дрруугоогоо языкaа - сскоопиpрууйтее иcсxхoодный теекcст, всстaавьтее eегoо в поолeе нижее, и выбeеpритeе нyужный чеекбоокcс языкаа

How to fix it? I check the text with the help of the service for checking the characters: raskladka.obmen-service.com

Comment: `var а = new List<string> { "а", "аa" };` wtf? What are you even trying to do with that code, I seriously can't tell.

Comment: @EpicKip letter "a" from English keyboard layout, but letter "а" from Russian keyboard layout. These are different letters. And I want to replace Russian characters with English ones in the text.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy res.Append(x[1][rnd.Next(0, x[1].Length)]) This code selects a random character from two possible

Comment: You always append original letter `res.Append(letter.ToString());`, even if before that you appended modified letter

Comment: @Behavior Still doesn't make sense to make a list for each possible letter and also you put this: `{ "а", "аa" }` in there.. what did you expect? 1 a will be replaced by 1 a. If you replace it by 2 you get a duplicate -_-

Comment: @Evk This is a temporary code. I just do not understand how to make the characters that are in the collection replace, and if there is no such symbol in the collection, then the original character was added to the text.

Comment: @EpicKip res.Append(x[1][rnd.Next(0, x[1].Length)]) I wrote above about this code, it does not create duplicates, it chooses a random symbol of two characters: english and russian, inserts into the text

Comment: @Behavior That still does not explain why you use a list for each character (maybe google dictionary...) and in that case I can't tell whats wrong with the output. And why is 1 of the 2 (english/russian) always 2 characters..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you replace letter with `res.Append(x[1][rnd.Next(0, x[1].Length)]);` later you still append base letter: `res.Append(letter.ToString());`
Try adding a condition:

```
        bool replaced = false;
        foreach (var x in alphavite)
        {
            if (x.Exists(e => e.EndsWith(letter.ToString())))
            {
                res.Append(x[1][rnd.Next(0, x[1].Length)]);
                replaced = true;
            }
        }
        if(!replaced)
            res.Append(letter.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should replace the English letter with its similar-looking Cyrillic equivalent from the Unicode character set, such as:

```
    var а = new List<string> { 'а', '\u0430' };
    var а = new List<string> { 'p', '\u0440' };
    var а = new List<string> { 'y', '\u0443' };
```